# Magento 2 wysiwyg editor filter image

Tags: magento2, image, wysiwyg, fieldsets

I have custom module field code is bellow for wysiwyg field:-

```
 $wysiwygConfig = $this->_wysiwygConfig->getConfig(['tab_id' => $this->getTabId()]);
    $fieldset->addField(
                'news_content',
                'editor',
                [
                    'name' => 'news_content',
                    'label' => __('Long Description'),
                    'title' => __('Long Description'),
                    'style' => 'height:11em',
                    'required' => true,
                    'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
                    'config' => $wysiwygConfig
                ]
            );
```

when i upload image in this field with content it only shows content and image is not come with proper tag as bellow:-

```
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/24.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p>test</p>
```

so there is a question that content filter we used in 1.9.X.X is not in magento 2.0.2.

how can i get image and description from `wysiwyg editor` with default filter to display image with content.

Comment: where you are using this???

Comment: using in admin edit page Custom\News\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Edit\Tab\Main.php

Answer (score 2):

Use below code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$objectManager->get('\Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider')->getBlockFilter()->filter($item->getContent());
```

In above code `$item->getContent()` is your editor content

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filter\Template')->getTemplateProcessor()->filter($attributeHtml);
```

Where $attributeHtml should be the content of editor.

Comment: it gives error Undefined property: Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output::$_getTemplateProcessor any solution for that.

Comment: I update my answer please check this now! and let me know

Comment: it gives blank page.

Comment: Do you use `echo $product` ??

Comment: no but did not load page

Comment: try to remove `->getTemplateProcessor()`

Comment: but image tag from editor not come proper any idea?

Comment: what is the response you get??

Comment: <img alt="" womens-category-tanks.jpg"}}"="" womens="" wysiwyg="" src="{{media url=">

Comment: now its come <img src="{{media url='wysiwyg/25.png'}}" alt="sdadsada"> but why image is not displaying?